# PHP trying to use str_replace()

Tags: php, str-replace

This is my current code:

```
$parcels = $api->parcels->get(); 

$url = (array_values($parcels)[0]['label']['label_printer']);
$goToUrl = $api->getUrl($url);

str_replace('/api/v2//api/v2/', '/api/v2/', $goToUrl);
print_r($goToUrl);
echo "<br />";
echo $url;
```

Why do I use `str_replace()`? because I am intending to redirect to `$goToUrl` and this is not working because the current API is giving me the link wrong.

This is my output:

```
https://api_key:api_secret@panel.sendcloud.nl/api/v2//api/v2/labels/label_printer/1369315
```

As you can see, **api/v2** comes in this link twice. I want to remove **/api/v2/** and then run the output. But my `str_replace();` is not performing. My output stays the same.

Can this even be achieved this way? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the str_replace line to:

```
$goToUrl = str_replace('/api/v2//api/v2/', '/api/v2/', $goToUrl);
```

Comment: DUDE THANKS! unbelievable i did not think of that.

Comment: @user1785684 big 1 haha. Sometimes i gotta take a look away from the screen and take a deep breath or a break and relook. To many times i overlook these small issues.